# Facebook Audience Network SDK file size too large

Tags: java, android, ads, facebook-audience-network

The Facebook Audience Network SDK is too large in file size, my app is around 500 KB, adding the SDK makes it 5 times larger in file size which is a bit ridiculous. Is there a lite version or is there a way to add just the parts that I need of it to decrease the size? Other SDKs like AdMob or UnityAds are very small in comparison, so I don't understand why is this one so large.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.2.0'
```

Thanks

Comment: The average Android app file size is 11.5MB; so unless your APK is significantly larger than that, you shouldn't worry. There is no lite version os FAN SDK, so I am afraid that is the only option.

Comment: That sucks, I know that most apps are pretty big in file size, most likely because they use a lot of third party libraries (and then you wonder why software is so buggy nowadays). I'm gonna think more about this, if I even need to add FAN because I heard that the fill rate is pretty low. Thanks!

Comment: right, so you can only use FAN to back fill. They only serve ads to users with Facebook app installed and logged in, and their quality check is unpredictable. About the size, as you  grow your app functionality, very soon you will realize that it is hard and not worthy to try to keep it small.